# I think I like this riddle

Tags: riddle

> My whole is a preference,
>   My prefix is an animal, 
>   My suffix is a girl,
>   My infix is sure, 
>   Change one letter, Switch it around, 
>   And it becomes colourless, Smells nice, but dangerous.

Comment: is the last part talking about the infix or whole word?

Comment: It’s talking about The whole word

Comment: May I ask: in such puzzles can the prefix, infix and suffix overlap? For example **stored** could be prefix **st** (saint), infill **tor** (hill), suffix **red** (colour).

Comment: Yes, they do overlap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Slightly incomplete answer**

I think you are

> RATHER.

My whole is a preference,

> "I would rather do X than Y."

My prefix is an animal,

> a RAT.

My suffix is a girl,

> yup, that's HER.

My infix is sure,

> or, to be more precise, *definite*: the definite article THE.

Change one letter, Switch it around,
And it becomes colourless, Smells nice, but dangerous.

> Not sure about this yet ("anagram but one of the six letters is different" is rather too diffuse for my mind to latch on to). ETHER isn't far off, but it really doesn't fit the description (you have to change *two* letters into one, and then there's no further switching). ... Hmm, I suppose it could be AETHER; it turns out that that's an acceptable spelling of the chemical name.

Title: "I think I like this riddle"

> "I rather like". Or "I'd rather read this riddle than yet another Riley". Oh, wait, this one *is* yet another Riley :-).

Comment: Correct! Can you guess how the title could link in to the word?

Comment: Could the anagram be rot13(nrgure) instead?

Comment: @hexomino Yeah, I was just coming to the same conclusion :-).

Comment: @RohitJose There are two obvious ways. I've put 'em both into my answer.

Comment: Well done! The first one is correct by the way, but the other is still interesting.